# "Найди решение", но "Задайте вопрос" в баннере

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено

Попался на глаза такой баннер ru.SO:

[image: Изображение]

Проблема в том, что в первой строке обращение на "ты", а во второй - на "вы".

Думаю, нужно привести к одному виду - либо "Найдите" и "Задайте", либо "Найди" и "Задай". Второй вариант субъективно кажется более побуждающим.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! О проблеме знаю, в ближайшее время обновлю баннеры.